# jquery element position relative to mouse pointer

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i make these chunk of code set the position of the tooltip element inside the browser edges and popup in other direction if there is not enough room to display it on curent location.

```
var etichetaSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
  y = e.clientY;
  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle for left and right. But you can apply the same technique for top/bottom.

I calculate the max position left value possible by getting the document width and substracting the width of the tooltip to get the variable `max_value`.

Have a look here:

```js
var etichetaSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');

var width = document.body.clientWidth;
var tooltip_width = etichetaSpan.clientWidth;
var max_value = width - tooltip_width;

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
 width = document.body.clientWidth;
    max_value = width - tooltip_width;
});

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
  y = e.clientY;
  etichetaSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  if(x + 20 < max_value){
   etichetaSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  } else {
   etichetaSpan.style.left = (x - (20 + tooltip_width)) + 'px';
  }
};
```

```css
#tooltip-span{
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<span id="tooltip-span">Tooltip!</span>
```

Comment: this is what i need to use it but it seems it doesnt work for my case https://jsfiddle.net/6h6bn1yL/

Comment: .... my bad ... i`m on chrome and it doesnt work but on firefox it works... any hints on this?

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: It didn't work because you had a different structure: https://jsfiddle.net/ybyz82qe/1/